# ColdFusion ImagePaste 500 error

Tags: function, coldfusion

I just started getting a 500 error on a site using the cf `ImagePaste()` function.

```
<cfscript> ImagePaste(image, watermark, 0, 0); </cfscript>
<cfset ImagePaste(image, watermark, 0, 0) />
```

I've tried it both ways above

The full source of the function is below - it works fine with the imagepaste commented out.

```
<cffunction name="watermark" access="public" 
    description="adds the carproof logo to a jpeg" output="yes" returntype="any">
    <cfargument name="path" required="yes" type="string" default=""  />
    <cfargument name="filename" required="yes" type="string" />

    <cfimage source="#path##filename#" name="image">
    <cfimage source="#basepath#../Images/carproof-watermark.png" 
        name="watermark">
    <!---cfscript> ImagePaste(image, watermark, 1, 1); </cfscript--->

    <cfimage action="write" destination="#path##filename#" 
        source="#image#" overwrite="yes"  />
</cffunction>
```

Here is the error I get:

```
500

ROOT CAUSE: 
coldfusion.runtime.EventHandlerException: Event handler exception.
    at coldfusion.runtime.AppEventInvoker.onRequest(AppEventInvoker.java:251)
    at coldfusion.filter.ApplicationFilter.invoke(ApplicationFilter.java:278)
    at coldfusion.filter.RequestMonitorFilter.invoke(RequestMonitorFilter.java:48)
    at coldfusion.filter.MonitoringFilter.invoke(MonitoringFilter.java:40)
    at coldfusion.filter.PathFilter.invoke(PathFilter.java:86)
    at coldfusion.filter.ExceptionFilter.invoke(ExceptionFilter.java:70)
    at coldfusion.filter.ClientScopePersistenceFilter.invoke(ClientScopePersistenceFilter.java:28)
    at coldfusion.filter.BrowserFilter.invoke(BrowserFilter.java:38)
    at coldfusion.filter.NoCacheFilter.invoke(NoCacheFilter.java:46)
    at coldfusion.filter.GlobalsFilter.invoke(GlobalsFilter.java:38)
    at coldfusion.filter.DatasourceFilter.invoke(DatasourceFilter.java:22)
    at coldfusion.filter.RequestThrottleFilter.invoke(RequestThrottleFilter.java:126)
    at coldfusion.CfmServlet.service(CfmServlet.java:198)
    at coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapServlet.service(BootstrapServlet.java:89)
    at jrun.servlet.FilterChain.doFilter(FilterChain.java:86)
    at coldfusion.monitor.event.MonitoringServletFilter.doFilter(MonitoringServletFilter.java:42)
    at coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapFilter.doFilter(BootstrapFilter.java:46)
    at jrun.servlet.FilterChain.doFilter(FilterChain.java:94)
    at jrun.servlet.FilterChain.service(FilterChain.java:101)
    at jrun.servlet.ServletInvoker.invoke(ServletInvoker.java:106)
    at jrun.servlet.JRunInvokerChain.invokeNext(JRunInvokerChain.java:42)
    at jrun.servlet.JRunRequestDispatcher.invoke(JRunRequestDispatcher.java:286)
    at jrun.servlet.ServletEngineService.dispatch(ServletEngineService.java:543)
    at jrun.servlet.jrpp.JRunProxyService.invokeRunnable(JRunProxyService.java:203)
    at jrunx.scheduler.ThreadPool$DownstreamMetrics.invokeRunnable(ThreadPool.java:320)
    at jrunx.scheduler.ThreadPool$ThreadThrottle.invokeRunnable(ThreadPool.java:428)
    at jrunx.scheduler.ThreadPool$UpstreamMetrics.invokeRunnable(ThreadPool.java:266)
    at jrunx.scheduler.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:66)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at coldfusion.image.Image.paste(Image.java:2307)
    at coldfusion.runtime.CFPage.ImagePaste(CFPage.java:5877)
    at cffile2ecfm1620657721$funcWATERMARK.runFunction(/var/www/vhosts/newride.ca/subdomains/admin/httpdocs/Assets/CFC/file.cfm:19)
    at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:418)
    at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ReturnTypeFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:360)
    at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ArgumentCollectionFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:324)
    at coldfusion.filter.FunctionAccessFilter.invoke(FunctionAccessFilter.java:59)
    at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.runFilterChain(UDFMethod.java:277)
    at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:192)
    at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._invokeUDF(CfJspPage.java:2471)
    at cffile2ecfm1620657721$funcUPLOAD.runFunction(/var/www/vhosts/newride.ca/subdomains/admin/httpdocs/Assets/CFC/file.cfm:91)
    at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:418)
    at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ReturnTypeFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:360)
    at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ArgumentCollectionFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:324)
    at coldfusion.filter.FunctionAccessFilter.invoke(FunctionAccessFilter.java:59)
    at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.runFilterChain(UDFMethod.java:277)
    at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:192)
    at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._invokeUDF(CfJspPage.java:2471)
    at cfimage2dupload2dtest2ecfm664365309.runPage(/var/www/vhosts/newride.ca/subdomains/admin/httpdocs/Assets/XHTML/image-upload-test.cfm:10)
    at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage.invoke(CfJspPage.java:196)
    at coldfusion.tagext.lang.IncludeTag.doStartTag(IncludeTag.java:483)
    at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._emptyTcfTag(CfJspPage.java:2661)
    at cfindex2ecfm1182266435.runPage(/var/www/vhosts/newride.ca/subdomains/admin/httpdocs/index.cfm:27)
    at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage.invoke(CfJspPage.java:196)
    at coldfusion.tagext.lang.IncludeTag.doStartTag(IncludeTag.java:483)
    at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._emptyTcfTag(CfJspPage.java:2661)
    at cfApplication2ecfc1506803272$funcONREQUEST.runFunction(/var/www/vhosts/newride.ca/subdomains/admin/httpdocs/Application.cfc:130)
    at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:418)
    at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ArgumentCollectionFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:324)
    at coldfusion.filter.FunctionAccessFilter.invoke(FunctionAccessFilter.java:59)
    at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.runFilterChain(UDFMethod.java:277)
    at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:192)
    at coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxy.invoke(TemplateProxy.java:448)
    at coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxy.invoke(TemplateProxy.java:308)
    at coldfusion.runtime.AppEventInvoker.invoke(AppEventInvoker.java:74)
    at coldfusion.runtime.AppEventInvoker.onRequest(AppEventInvoker.java:243)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.media.jai.util.PropertyUtil.getString(PropertyUtil.java:159)
    at javax.media.jai.JaiI18N.getString(JaiI18N.java:22)
    at javax.media.jai.OperationRegistry.initializeRegistry(OperationRegistry.java:357)
    at javax.media.jai.JAI.<clinit>(JAI.java:560)
    ... 63 more

javax.servlet.ServletException: ROOT CAUSE: 
coldfusion.runtime.EventHandlerException: Event handler exception.
    at coldfusion.runtime.AppEventInvoker.onRequest(AppEventInvoker.java:251)
    at coldfusion.filter.ApplicationFilter.invoke(ApplicationFilter.java:278)
    at coldfusion.filter.RequestMonitorFilter.invoke(RequestMonitorFilter.java:48)
    at coldfusion.filter.MonitoringFilter.invoke(MonitoringFilter.java:40)
    at coldfusion.filter.PathFilter.invoke(PathFilter.java:86)
    at coldfusion.filter.ExceptionFilter.invoke(ExceptionFilter.java:70)
    at coldfusion.filter.ClientScopePersistenceFilter.invoke(ClientScopePersistenceFilter.java:28)
    at coldfusion.filter.BrowserFilter.invoke(BrowserFilter.java:38)
    at coldfusion.filter.NoCacheFilter.invoke(NoCacheFilter.java:46)
    at coldfusion.filter.GlobalsFilter.invoke(GlobalsFilter.java:38)
    at coldfusion.filter.DatasourceFilter.invoke(DatasourceFilter.java:22)
    at coldfusion.filter.RequestThrottleFilter.invoke(RequestThrottleFilter.java:126)
    at coldfusion.CfmServlet.service(CfmServlet.java:198)
    at coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapServlet.service(BootstrapServlet.java:89)
    at jrun.servlet.FilterChain.doFilter(FilterChain.java:86)
    at coldfusion.monitor.event.MonitoringServletFilter.doFilter(MonitoringServletFilter.java:42)
    at coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapFilter.doFilter(BootstrapFilter.java:46)
    at jrun.servlet.FilterChain.doFilter(FilterChain.java:94)
    at jrun.servlet.FilterChain.service(FilterChain.java:101)
    at jrun.servlet.ServletInvoker.invoke(ServletInvoker.java:106)
    at jrun.servlet.JRunInvokerChain.invokeNext(JRunInvokerChain.java:42)
    at jrun.servlet.JRunRequestDispatcher.invoke(JRunRequestDispatcher.java:286)
    at jrun.servlet.ServletEngineService.dispatch(ServletEngineService.java:543)
    at jrun.servlet.jrpp.JRunProxyService.invokeRunnable(JRunProxyService.java:203)
    at jrunx.scheduler.ThreadPool$DownstreamMetrics.invokeRunnable(ThreadPool.java:320)
    at jrunx.scheduler.ThreadPool$ThreadThrottle.invokeRunnable(ThreadPool.java:428)
    at jrunx.scheduler.ThreadPool$UpstreamMetrics.invokeRunnable(ThreadPool.java:266)
    at jrunx.scheduler.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:66)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at coldfusion.image.Image.paste(Image.java:2307)
    at coldfusion.runtime.CFPage.ImagePaste(CFPage.java:5877)
    at cffile2ecfm1620657721$funcWATERMARK.runFunction(/var/www/vhosts/newride.ca/subdomains/admin/httpdocs/Assets/CFC/file.cfm:19)
    at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:418)
    at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ReturnTypeFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:360)
    at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ArgumentCollectionFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:324)
    at coldfusion.filter.FunctionAccessFilter.invoke(FunctionAccessFilter.java:59)
    at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.runFilterChain(UDFMethod.java:277)
    at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:192)
    at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._invokeUDF(CfJspPage.java:2471)
    at cffile2ecfm1620657721$funcUPLOAD.runFunction(/var/www/vhosts/newride.ca/subdomains/admin/httpdocs/Assets/CFC/file.cfm:91)
    at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:418)
    at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ReturnTypeFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:360)
    at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ArgumentCollectionFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:324)
    at coldfusion.filter.FunctionAccessFilter.invoke(FunctionAccessFilter.java:59)
    at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.runFilterChain(UDFMethod.java:277)
    at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:192)
    at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._invokeUDF(CfJspPage.java:2471)
    at cfimage2dupload2dtest2ecfm664365309.runPage(/var/www/vhosts/newride.ca/subdomains/admin/httpdocs/Assets/XHTML/image-upload-test.cfm:10)
    at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage.invoke(CfJspPage.java:196)
    at coldfusion.tagext.lang.IncludeTag.doStartTag(IncludeTag.java:483)
    at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._emptyTcfTag(CfJspPage.java:2661)
    at cfindex2ecfm1182266435.runPage(/var/www/vhosts/newride.ca/subdomains/admin/httpdocs/index.cfm:27)
    at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage.invoke(CfJspPage.java:196)
    at coldfusion.tagext.lang.IncludeTag.doStartTag(IncludeTag.java:483)
    at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._emptyTcfTag(CfJspPage.java:2661)
    at cfApplication2ecfc1506803272$funcONREQUEST.runFunction(/var/www/vhosts/newride.ca/subdomains/admin/httpdocs/Application.cfc:130)
    at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:418)
    at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ArgumentCollectionFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:324)
    at coldfusion.filter.FunctionAccessFilter.invoke(FunctionAccessFilter.java:59)
    at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.runFilterChain(UDFMethod.java:277)
    at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:192)
    at coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxy.invoke(TemplateProxy.java:448)
    at coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxy.invoke(TemplateProxy.java:308)
    at coldfusion.runtime.AppEventInvoker.invoke(AppEventInvoker.java:74)
    at coldfusion.runtime.AppEventInvoker.onRequest(AppEventInvoker.java:243)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.media.jai.util.PropertyUtil.getString(PropertyUtil.java:159)
    at javax.media.jai.JaiI18N.getString(JaiI18N.java:22)
    at javax.media.jai.OperationRegistry.initializeRegistry(OperationRegistry.java:357)
    at javax.media.jai.JAI.<clinit>(JAI.java:560)
    ... 63 more

    at coldfusion.monitor.event.MonitoringServletFilter.doFilter(MonitoringServletFilter.java:70)
    at coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapFilter.doFilter(BootstrapFilter.java:46)
    at jrun.servlet.FilterChain.doFilter(FilterChain.java:94)
    at jrun.servlet.FilterChain.service(FilterChain.java:101)
    at jrun.servlet.ServletInvoker.invoke(ServletInvoker.java:106)
    at jrun.servlet.JRunInvokerChain.invokeNext(JRunInvokerChain.java:42)
    at jrun.servlet.JRunRequestDispatcher.invoke(JRunRequestDispatcher.java:286)
    at jrun.servlet.ServletEngineService.dispatch(ServletEngineService.java:543)
    at jrun.servlet.jrpp.JRunProxyService.invokeRunnable(JRunProxyService.java:203)
    at jrunx.scheduler.ThreadPool$DownstreamMetrics.invokeRunnable(ThreadPool.java:320)
    at jrunx.scheduler.ThreadPool$ThreadThrottle.invokeRunnable(ThreadPool.java:428)
    at jrunx.scheduler.ThreadPool$UpstreamMetrics.invokeRunnable(ThreadPool.java:266)
    at jrunx.scheduler.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:66)
```

Comment: What is the full error message (including stack trace)?

Comment: Can you provide example watermark and uploaded files? What happens if you run just this function against those files? That is don't run it through the `upload()` function.

Comment: running the function alone produces the same results: you can see it here: http://propaganda.bigblock.ca/filetest/ - just click on the test.cfm - sample files are there as well. -thanks

Comment: @Sean - It works without error under 9,0,1,274733 and 8,0,1,195765 too. What is your version? The image paths also look a little funny. Ignoring scoping for a second, does `<cfimage action="writeToBrowser" source="#watermark#">` display a valid image?

Comment: Hmm.. I am running 8,0,1,195765 - interesting error with the image tag: "Security: The requested template has been denied access to /opt/coldfusion8/tmpCache." This path does not exist on the server...

Comment: @Sean - An error using `action="writeToBrowser"`? Certain tags like cfimage, cfchart, ... use temp files/directories. Sounds like a permissions/sandbox problem. You may need to tweak your configuration. Or just write the image to disk an use an `<img>` tag for now. Just to see if `source="#basepath#../Images/carproof-watermark.png"` actually results in a valid image.

Comment: @leigh: thanks, I am still having this problem, I tried the writetobrowser action & got an error 'can't write to /opt/coldfusion8/tmpCache' - directory did not exist, I created it and the writetobrowser action now works - though it did not solve the original 500 error. still getting that. I updated to java 1.6.0_26, applied the cumulative hotfix 4 package AND the cfimage tag patch... no effect.

Comment: @Sean - Like I said, I tested under 2 installs and had no problems with those files. Maybe something is messed up in your configuration. Check your log files. Also what happens if you try the same code on another machine?

Comment: @Leigh, yes - this is screaming permissions, but what where? no idea where I could begin to troubleshoot this.  Logs are similar to the browser dump: 06/26 16:35:27 Error [jrpp-151] - Could not initialize class javax.media.jai.JAI The specific sequence of files included or processed is: /var/www/vhosts/bigblock.ca/subdomains/propaganda/httpdocs/filetest/test.cfm, line: 19
06/26 16:35:27 error ROOT CAUSE:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class javax.media.jai.JAI

Comment: @Sean - The `writeToBrowser` problem sounded like permissions.. but you seemed to have fixed that. The `NoClassDefFoundError` error seems like something else, such as a problem with your class path. Beyond that I am not sure.

Comment: @Leigh - yes, the tmp directory was actually missing altogether, somewhat alarming, what else is missing? I did messa around with the classpath, explicitly referencing the new Java location, but go nothing. I don't know what to do next.

Comment: @Sean - Did this function *ever* work on your server?

Comment: @Leigh - Yes it did, one day it just stopped working. no updates were done no maintenance ... worked fine for about 2 years... far as I can tell 'out of the blue'  wondering if some file went bad somewhere ... disk issues/permissions, I don't know where to look.

Comment: @Sean - Well things do not usually just stop working. Something must have changed. I do not know enough about your server to guess what it might be. Other than suggesting a reinstall, my only thought is see if you can find out more details about your javax.media.jai.JAI / NoClassDefFoundError error.

Comment: @Leigh - sorry, thought I had posted the environment somewhere. Centos DV at MediaTemple, it's a live production server, so a reinstall is an absolute last option - actually migrating to a new server would be less painful! - I agree, things do not change on their own however, I just got a call from the client one day that they were getting this error after 2+ years of smooth sailing.

Comment: cont: I've tried replacing th jai_*.jar files, tested other image functions, some work & some don't: functions that gather information [imageinfo(), imageGetWidth(), etc] seem to work while those that manipulate the image don't [imagePaste(), imageCopy(), imageBlur(), etc] all throwing the same error.

Comment: @Sean - Many image functions use JAI. So given the given the message *could not initialize ...JAI* it makes sense those functions would not work either. First I would make sure the class path did not get mucked up (missing jar, too many jars, etc..). That is the most common cause of problems. But `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` errors are a pain to figure out. http://mindprod.com/jgloss/runerrormessages.html#NOCLASSDEFFOUNDERROR. Just guesswork, but looking closer it +might+ be initialization problem `Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError`?

Comment: (cont): I know JAI reads some property files from the jars when starting up. Maybe they are not accessible for some reason (missing, permissions, ..)? I am not running Centos. So that is my best guess for now. Hopefully someone else on HOF or the adobe forums knows more ..

Comment: @leigh - I don't know which one yet, but that provided the clue [even though I have been over the classpath before] - looking in {cfhome}lib/updates/ I find all the update files from patches & hotfixes, moving all these out of the classpath & restarting solves the problem [introducing who knows what!] - there must be a conflict, it's possible I forgot to remove one of the jars as the kb articles indicate. I'll just have to reapply the updates & test as I go to see which one.  Leigh, thanks. can you post that as the answer & I can mark it as solved? [since it was your clue!]

Comment: @Sean - Just testing SO's [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/981/discussion-between-leigh-and-sean)

Comment: @Sean - When you finally figure out which one it is, let use know. I am very curious!

Comment: @leigh - I did get everything working again, I'm not sure exactly what the problem was, but here is what I did to solve it: chf8010002.jar & chf8010003.jar existed in my {home}lib/updates/ directory - they should have been removed when I installed HF4 - deleted them, downloaded & reinstalled HF4, restart, no effect on the image issue. hf800-70523.jar, hf801-00002.jar also existed, hf800-70523.jar is actually for CF8.0!, deleted, rolled back the CFIDE directory changes, restart, no effect. this leaves me with the newly applied chf8010004.jar & hf801-71557.jar[the image update]

Comment: Reinstalling the image hotfix [again!] seems to now have fixed the problem, but I still don't know what the actual issue was. [bad download??]  of course now there is a new issue - but will post that in a new question.

Comment: @Sean - Possibly too many versions of the same library in the class path? If you had the time, you could compare the jars/contents you removed against the ones you reinstalled to identify what is different. But sounds like you have other fish to fry ..

Comment: @leigh - true dat!, thanks for sticking with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> tested other image functions, some
>   work & some don't:

Many image functions use JAI. So given the message `Could not initialize class javax.media.jai.JAI` it makes sense those functions would not work either.  First I would make sure the class path did not get mucked up (missing jar, too many jars, etc..). That is the most common cause of problems.

But `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` errors are [a pain to figure out](http://mindprod.com/jgloss/runerrormessages.html#NOCLASSDEFFOUNDERROR). Just guesswork, but looking closer it might be initialization problem `Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError`. I know JAI reads some property files from the jars when starting up. Maybe they are not accessible for some reason (missing, permissions, ..)? I am not running Centos. So that is my best guess for now.

Answer (score 0):

Might be time to offload image manipulation to a 3rd party binary.

Imagemagick, pil, gd etc.

Are you running CF on OS X? (as we do)

The JAI library that ships with OS X's Java is an older version compared to the latest on my Windows machine. Some image editing features, for us, simply dont work on our Mac dev environments, but work perfectly in their Windows equivalents.